# How to find the outer keys in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a large nested JSON in python, which I've converted to a dictionary. In it, there's a key called 'achievements' in some sub-dictionary (don't know how far it's nested). This sub-dictionary is itself either an element of a list, or the value of a key in a larger dictionary.

Assuming all I know is that this key is called 'achievements', how can I get its value? It's fine to assume that the key's 'achievements' name is unique in the entire dictionary at all levels.

Comment: Please give at least one sample and it's better to let us know the code that you may have tried for your task.

Comment: Just curious why the other answer was deleted? I ran the code and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSONPath](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00.html) to find this and almost any sort of search path within json quite easily. See the [`jsonpath-ng`](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/) library for an example.

In your case, the JSONPath `$..achievements` will give you what you need.

PS: While you can absolutely write a recursive function to search through the dictionary, JsonPath allows you to write more complex queries, retrieve multiple results, etc. and is a more powerful tool to have in your arsenal.